# python list is not copying

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, copy

In the following subset problem, I'm trying to make a copy of a list object

```
def findFourPlus(itemCount, seq, goal):
    goalDifference = float("inf")
    closestPartial = []
    subset_sum(itemCount, seq, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial=[])
    print(closestPartial)


def subset_sum(itemCount, seq, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if(len(partial) == itemCount):
        if s == goal:
            print(partial)
    else:
        if( abs(goal - s) < goalDifference):
            goalDifference = abs(goal - s)
            print(goalDifference)
            print(partial)
            print(closestPartial)
            closestPartial = copy.deepcopy(partial)        

for i in range(len(seq)):
    n = seq[i]
    remaining = seq[i+1:]
    subset_sum(itemCount, remaining, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial + [n])
```

in the subset function, I am trying to make a copy of the **`partial`** list to **`closestPartial`**. I've tried

```
closestPartial = partial
closestPartial = list[:]
closestPartial = list(partial)
closestPartial = copy.copy(partial)
closestPartial = copy.deepcopy(partial)
```

but in the end all of them seems to be futile. closestPartial remains to be an empty list (which is what I initiated to) for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing closestPartial in as a parameter, so the only thing that will work is an inplace update of its list. All of the examples you give replace the list that was in closestPartial with a new list. But since it wasn't the list you passed in, it doesn't update the real list.

Try:

```
closestPartial[:] = partial
```

You can get a feel for the problem by printing the list id before and after the operation.

```
print id(closestPartial)
...some operation
print id(closestPartial)
```

if the id changes, that means you created a new list and didn't update the one passed in.

**EDIT**

Seems I need a better explanation... when you call `subset_sum`, it creates a local variable called `closestPartial` that references whatever was passed in as a parameter, in this case a list known to the caller as `closestPartial`. You now have two variables pointing to the same list. If you reassign the variable, like in `closestPartial = partial`, those two variables now point to different lists. You didn't update the caller's pointer, you just changed the local variable. Instead, if you don't reassign, changes you make to the one list referenced by both variables are seen by the caller as well - because its the same list.

Comment: Doesn't this act the same way as :
closestPartial = partial ?

Comment: Hi @Yousef_Shamshoum - see my update. `closestPartial = partial` assigns partial to the local variable called closestPartial. The thing you wanted to update - that is, what closestPartial was before the assignment - is lost.

Comment: ...the `[:]` notation does in-place replacement.

Comment: Just a quick question, is it possible that the goalDifference is suffering from the same problem? I am printing out some data and it appears it is forever stuck at infinite value

Comment: I'm not sure... but it doesn't seem so from a quick look. goalDifference is being set to a different value in the function, just like partialDifference... the question is whether the caller is depending on the calculated value from the subroutine (that would be bad). From what I can tell, the caller doesn't care if the function changes its own internal value.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `goalDifference` is suffering from the same problem, if you change it in a function and then expect the changed value to somehow get back to the calling function.

Here's some (Python 2 style) code to illustrate what's happening:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def testA(update_func):
    seq = []
    num = 1
    for _ in range(5):
        newnum = update_func(seq, num)
        print 'testA:  ', num, seq, newnum
    print

def testB(update_func):
    seq = []
    num = 1
    for _ in range(5):
        num = update_func(seq, num)
        print 'testB:  ', num, seq
    print


def update0(seq, num):
    #This creates a new list
    seq = seq + [num]
    num = num + 1
    print 'update0:', num, seq
    return num

def update1(seq, num):
    #This updates the existing list
    seq.append(num)
    num += 1
    print 'update1:', num, seq
    return num

def update2(seq, num):
    #This updates the existing list
    seq[:] = seq + [num]
    num += 1
    print 'update2:', num, seq
    return num

def update3(seq, num):
    #This updates the existing list
    seq += [num]
    num += 1
    print 'update2:', num, seq
    return num


update_funcs = (update0, update1, update2, update3)
for f in update_funcs:
    testA(f)

print '------\n'

for f in update_funcs:
    testB(f)
```

Stack Overflow member Ned Batchelder's article [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) has a good explanation, with cute diagrams.

Comment: thanks for the link! really helpful information, definitely will take a look at it in the future. As for the problem, I am still a bit lost, so I think i'll be opening a new question entirely since the original question was solved